# Разметка страницы, обзор кода

Tags: html, css

Доброе утро, скажите пожалуйста, есть ли в моем коде какие либо ошибки, например в разметке, padding или margin.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #FCFCFE;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #3E4554;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 0.8;
  margin-left: 36px;
}
/* Основной блок на верхнего меню */
.div_0 {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 12px;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Поиск */
form {
  padding-left: 134px;
  margin: 0;
}

input {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 27px;
  background: url("/images/search.png") no-repeat scroll;
  background-position: 7px 11px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
}

::placeholder {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: #3E4554;
}

/* Первое меню */
.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 42px;
}

.nav  :first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 42px;
  color: #3E4554;
  transition: color .2s linear;
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: #6A7BFF;
}

/* Второе меню */
.nav_1 {
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 13px;
}

.nav_1 a {
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: #CFD3DC;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav_1 a:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.nav_1 a:hover {
  color: #B9BCC4;
}

.program-work {
  list-style: none;
}

.program-work a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3E4554;
}

.menu {
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-top: 38px;
}

.menu a {
  transition: color .1s linear;
}

.menu a:hover {
  color: #6A7BFF;
}

.name-program {
  padding-top: 18px;
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.name-program a {
  transition: color .1s linear;
}

.name-program a:hover {
  color: #6A7BFF;
}

.name-program-view {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 45px;
}

.name-program-view a {
  transition: color .2s linear;
}

.name-program-view a:hover {
  color: #6A7BFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/profile.css">
</head>
<body>
    <Header>
    <div class="div_0">
            <a class="logo" href="#" alt="logo">logo</a>
    
    <form action="/search"  method="post">
        <input type="search" results=5 size="13" name="" placeholder="Поиск" class="input" />
    </form>

    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="leftmenutop"><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
        <li class="left__menu_top"><a href="#">Рейтинг</a></li>
        <li class="left__menu_top"><a href="#">Соревнования</a></li>
        <li class="left__menu_top"><a href="#">Событие</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="nav_1">
        <a class="fas fa-bell" href="#"></a>
        <a class="fas fa-cog" href="#"></a>
        <a class="fas fa-plus" href="#"></a>
        <a class="fas fa-user-alt" href="#"></a>
    </div>
</div>
    </Header>

    <ul class="program-work">
        <li class="menu"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
        <li class="name-program"><a href="#">Программы тренировок</a></li>
        <li class="name-program-view"><a href="#">Отжимания</a></li>
        <li class="name-program-view"><a href="#">Подтягивания</a></li>
        <li class="name-program-view"><a href="#">Приседания</a></li>
        <li class="name-program-view"><a href="#">Брусья</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема смещения при задании `padding-top` в том, что для класса `.images` Вы задали абсолютное позиционирование. А это значит, что его местоположение определяется относительно положения родительского блока с относительным позиционированием. Положение родителя Вы и смещаете, задавая верхний отступ.

Но вот корень проблемы в том, что подходы в вёрстке выбраны неправильные. Очень много ошибок. И решить проблему - значит очень многое переделывать.

Comment: Не могли бы вы указать на ошибки, которые есть в коде, я только учусь и это моя первая верстка.

Comment: Там сплошные ошибки. Продолжайте учиться

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста сейчас, обновил код, можете ли вы сделать какие либо замечание в написании кода. Решил делать все с начала и поэтапно.